# value added when they have the same point x

Tags: highcharts

Elaborating a graph where I point with y different, and 'x' equals; I put in the series:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Grafico 1',
                data: data,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2)
                               },
                                color: "#000000"
                },
                stacking: 'normal',
            }]
```

and as a result in the chart have the highest value added with the smaller one, that is:
http://i.imgur.com/Ups7AzT.png

If I remove the statement "stacking: 'normal'", I instead the chart without the line joining the points:
http://i.imgur.com/gMAO5VW.png

I ask: you can have the chart without the value added is greater than the lower (ie the value 18 is represented as 18 in the chart, and 26.45 because the child is 8.45)?

Comment: Do you want to display stacked value in dataLabels? For all series or the top one only?

Comment: ok, my mistake in assigning values to the variable date! excuse me ..